# What is Difference between " new { onclick = "return validateform()" }" and new { onclick = "validateform()" },

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between,
`new { onclick = "return validateform()" }` and

`new { onclick = "validateform()" }`,

i.e. A method with return type and without return type in this case, what is the difference?

The complete line of code is here, if it returns `validateform()` function that where it will be returned

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditEmp", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divedit" }, new { onclick = "return validateform()" }))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new { onclick = "return validateform()" }` results in an HTML attribute

`<... onclick="return validateform()" />`

which validates the form and returns the result to the `onclick` *event source*. This way you can cancel the event for example.

`new { onclick = "validateform()" }` results in an HTML attribute

`<... onclick="validateform()" />`

whereas no value is returned to the `onclick` *event source* hence the default is used (event is not canceled).

:edit

`new {}` is simply C# syntax for creating an anonymous object and *event source* is a weak term as it sometimes depends on the libraries you use. e.g. `jQuery` can register for `onclick` and listen for a return value, see [Event handler's parameters, this binding, and the return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Event_handler's_parameters_this_binding_and_the_return_value) and  [The event handler processing algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm).

Comment: Thank you. Here what does 'new { }' keyword do? and onclick event source means does it takes control towards form submission event?

Comment: Thank you so much:)